# Sending notification one hour before competition starts

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, c#-4.0, async-await, backgroundworker

I have background worker service contain starting time of competition i need to push notification before one hour from started what is the best way to handle timing issue i read about task.delay its good choice for this situation ?
 Note that there is a possibility to wait for days.